# How do I make a JavaScript function that Displays the elements contained in a NEW div every time a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want JS function that will make the first click of the button display the images located inside the container "myDIV1" and the second click display the images inside of "myDIV2" and third click display the images inside of "myDIV3" and son on and so forth all the way up to "myDIV76." I am not good at all with javascript which is why I came here for help. All of the images inside of the myDIV's displays are set to "none" and I want to function to set them to "blocks" but The only thing im struggling with it getting the button to display each DIV while keep all of the previously added ones there (just like a "load more images" button like youtube has at the bottom of a page.)

Answer (score 1):

Add a click handler to the button, set a counter that uses the value of the counter to show the appropriate div, and increment the counter on click.

```js
var count = 1;
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function() {
  var target = document.getElementById('div'+count)
  target && target.classList.remove('hidden');
  count++;
})
```

```css
.hidden {display:none;}
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>

<div id="div1" class="hidden">div1</div>
<div id="div2" class="hidden">div2</div>
<div id="div3" class="hidden">div3</div>
<div id="div4" class="hidden">div4</div>
<div id="div5" class="hidden">div5</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and it makes the first div appear, but does not allow the other 5 to show up... :/

Comment: yes, I dont know if it is how I set up my page or not, but that is just text in the demo. Will it work if inside of the div instead of text I have * images?

Comment: is there a way that i can copy and past my page code and send it to you without having to go through each line and indent?

Comment: @HeathHorn Doesn't matter what's in the divs. But this goes beyond the purpose of Stack Overflow. It's your responsibility to make a post that reproduces the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Few things here,

1. add click event on button with class `showmore` ex: `$(".showmore").on("click", function() {...}`
2. since `hiddenImg` is a class with css to hide, we can use `var imgArr = $(".hiddenImg").first();` to find the first div with img that are still `hidden`. Then if we found one hidden img, we remove the hidden class `hiddenImg`, the img become visible.

   `if(imgArr.length > 0){
           imgArr.removeClass("hiddenImg");
   }`
3. each time you click the button, it will find the next hidden image and display it, until you can not find anymore, by doing this, no matter how many images you have, no need to update the js code.

hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".showmore").on("click", function() {
 var imgArr = $(".hiddenImg").first();

 if(imgArr.length > 0){
  imgArr.removeClass("hiddenImg");
 }
  });
});
```

```css
.showmore {
  left: 250px;
  position: fixed;
}

.hiddenImg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="showmore">show more</button>
<div id="myDIV2" class="hiddenImg">img 2<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" /></div>
<div id="myDIV3" class="hiddenImg">img 3<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" /></div>
<div id="myDIV4" class="hiddenImg">img 4<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" /></div>
<div id="myDIV5" class="hiddenImg">img 5<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" /></div>
<div id="myDIV6" class="hiddenImg">img 6<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" /></div>
<div id="myDIV7" class="hiddenImg">img 7<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" /></div>
```